# $f(x) \rightarrow \infty $ when $x\rightarrow 1^+$

Tags: calculus, analysis

I want to prove that $f(x) \rightarrow \infty $ when $x\rightarrow 1^+$. My tactic is to prove that no matter how big you choose a $N\in \mathbb{R}$, you can always find a $\delta>0$ so the following statement is true:

> $ f(x) > N $ for all $x\in \left] 1, 1+\delta \right[$

Is my technique correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the statement means.

Comment: It's correct, but unless we don't see your explicit details we can't know if you worked out your tactic right. If you worked out things to show what you said about your function $f$, then you're good to go.